# Authenticating with Firebase token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've authenticated a test user in my Firebase database using the code below:

```
  login(email, password) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Nice, it worked!', value);
        this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)
          .then((idToken) => {
            // print out token
            console.log('Id token -> ', idToken);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });
  }
```

At this location for this user I have a list of courses:

[image]

And the rules on this database are as follows:

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to test, in Postman, to see if I can hit the database for this user and get back a list of users at the location but I either get back `not found` or the Google sign on screen.

Is it possible to send the authorization token as a header when you use Firebase tokens? Or is that just for Google OAuth tokens?

According to this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#firebase_id_tokens) I should be-able to hit the database and get back my data by doing something like the following:

```
curl "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/users/ada/name.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>"
```

which in my case should look like this:

```
curl "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/<GUID>/courses?auth=<ID_TOKEN>"
```

My Postman request header looks like this:

**Key**                **Value**

Authorization          *firebase-token*

Comment: When you use the firebase database api, what does the request look like?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question would you care to explain why?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat do you mean when I try the same request via the API? I haven't tried it yet. Will try it soon and report back

Comment: You don't have any rules for courses so Firebase will use the default rules which are false.